# Trouble doing a bitwise xor + bit_count in mysql

Tags: mysql, xor, phash, bitcount

I am trying to perform a comparison on hash values (hexadecimal strings of 16 characters). I have a MYSQL table that stores those values with a `phash VARCHAR(16)` column.
This is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT phash, bit_count(phash ^ x'dda15873a3de013d') FROM mytable;
```

But the bit_count + xor is not done correctly. Even for `phash='dda15873a3de013d'` I get `33` as a result whereas I should get `0` (the two hex are the same, so the xor should yield only zeros, hence a bit_count of 0.

What is wrong?
Thank you

Edit: 
example here => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7f5c2/1/0

```
mysql> SELECT phash,BIT_COUNT(CONV(phash, 16, 10) ^ 0xdda15873a3de012d) from mytable limit 1;

+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| phash            | BIT_COUNT(CONV(phash, 16, 10) ^ 0xdda15873a3de012d) |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| dda15873a3de012d |                                                  33 |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/54806. What data type does `phash` has?

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7f5c2/1/0

Comment: If the value is HEX you should use an appropriate data type in the first place for the column.

Comment: what type? what I got from the mysql doc was that there was no HEX data type for tables, and so I needed to store them as strings or varchar

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7f5c2/20. You could use `bit_count(hex('dda15873a3de013d') ^ hex(phash)`

Comment: Strangely this new one will always return 0, even when it's not supposed to. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7f5c2/24

Answer (score 1):

`CONV` returns a string. You need to cast the result of `CONV` to `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: I was having exactly the same issue, and CASTing the result of CONV sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `^` operator only works on integers. It can't be used to XOR strings (or blobs) with each other.

If your strings specifically represent *hexadecimal* integers, you can use `^` after converting them to integers:

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(CONV(phash, 16, 10) ^ 0xdda15873a3de013d)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting 33 instead of 0. I have edited my question to show the result I get for this query (more readable than in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(cast(CONV(phash, 16, 10) as unsigned) ^ 0xdda15873a3de013d)
```